# constexpr function returning string literal

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constexpr, c-strings

A function returning a copy of an integer literal

```
int number()
{ return 1; }
```

can be easily converted to a plain compile-time expression using the keyword `constexpr`.

```
constexpr int number()
{ return 1; }
```

However, I'm getting confused when it comes to string literals. The usual method is returning a pointer to `const char` that points to the string literal,

```
const char* hello()
{ return "hello world"; }
```

but I think that merely changing "const" to `constexpr` is not what I want (as a bonus, it also produces the compiler warning *deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'* using gcc 4.7.1)

```
constexpr char* hello()
{ return "hello world"; }
```

Is there a way to implement `hello()` in such a way that the call is substituted with a constant expression in the example below?

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << hello() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`const` and `constexpr` are [not interchangeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const), in your case you do not want to drop the `const` but you want to add `constexpr` like so:

```
constexpr const char* hello()
{
  return "hello world";
}
```

The warning you receive when you drop `const`, is because a *string literal* is an `array of n const char` and so a pointer to a *string literal* should be a *const char ** but in *C* a *string literal* is an array of char even though it is undefined behavior to attempt to modify them it was kept around for backwards compatibility but is depreciated so it should be avoided.

Comment: Makes sense, than you. What about a `constexpr` array, is there any difference under the hood between `constexpr const char* ptrToLiteral = "hello";` and `constexpr char cstring[] = "hello";`? If so, what? Is the latter stored in a different way?

Comment: @user1062874 yes, the second case `cstring` is an modifiable array that will be initialized with a copy of the string literal `"hello"` while the first case `ptrToLiteral` will just be pointing to a string literal.

Comment: I'm confused, note that in the original comment `cstring` is defined as `constexpr`, so it should not be modifiable, and attempting to modify `cstring` like `cstring[0] = 'a';` expectedly results in the error _assignment of read-only location 'cstring[0]'_

Comment: @user1062874 poor choice of words, `cstring` won't be modifiable in this case b/c it is a constexpr but would be otherwise.

Comment: I thought that this would be better expressed as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550084/difference-between-string-literal-and-constexpr-array-of-char

Answer (score 2):

Force constexpr evaluation:

```
constexpr const char * hi = hello();
std::cout << hi << std::endl;
```