# Difference between string literal and constexpr array of char

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, string-literals

I have been wondering if there is any difference between what is being pointed by `ptrToArray` and `ptrToLiteral` in the following example:

```
constexpr char constExprArray[] = "hello";
const char* ptrToArray = constExprArray;

const char* ptrToLiteral = "hello";
```

- Is my understanding that `constExprArray` and the two `"hello"` literals are all compile time constant lvalues correct?
- If so, is there any difference in how they are stored in the executable file, or is it purely compiler implementation or platform specific?
- Are they treated differently at runtime behind the scenes?
- Anything else to know about?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A string literal and a constexpr array of char are almost identical.  A pointer to either is an address constant expression.  An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is permitted on their elements in a constant expression.  They both have static storage duration.  The only difference that I know of is that a string literal can initialize an array whereas a constexpr array cannot:

```
constexpr char a[] = "hello";

constexpr char b[] = a; // ill-formed
constexpr char b[] = "hello"; // ok
```

To get around this you can wrap the array in a class of literal type.  We are currently looking at standardizing such a wrapper that will be called `std::string_literal` or similar, but for now you will have to do this by hand.