# Difference between const and constexpr pointer

Tags: c++

What is the difference between the following two pointer definitions

```
int i = 0;
const int *p = &i;
constexpr int *cp = &i;
```

Comment: That one compiles, whilst the other doesn't.  (http://ideone.com/NIO41u)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth You're the one who put it inside a function body, causing the error. That's not in the question.

Comment: @hvd: That's a fair point.

Comment: It's not a `const` or `constexpr` pointer. It's a pointer to a `const`/`constexpr` `int`.

Comment: `constexpr const int *ccp = &i;` is another possibility

Comment: @0x499602D2 according to c++ primer `constexpr *p` is a constant pointer to int and not a pointer to a const int

Comment: This has a "to which does the modifier apply, the pointer or the pointee" angle which the proposed duplicate did not.  Therefore, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @cmidi Yes, you're right. My mistake. In the duplicate it even says "`constexpr` always refers to the expression being declared (here `NP`), while `const` refers to `int` (it declares a pointer-to-const)" for the declaration `constexpr const int *NP = &N;`

Comment: Can't a very complete answer be found in this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const

Comment: @BenVoigt The duplicate's answer addresses that point as well (see my above comment).

Comment: @Silverspur there's a lot of info there but it doesn't seem to clearly state things for simple cases (e.g. it doesn't say whether there is any difference between `const int N = 5;` and `constexpr int N = 5;` )

Comment: @Matt You're right. Actually, I was just passing by and I remembered the other question. Sorry I did not take time to carefully read this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const int *p = &i;` means:

- `p` is non-const: it can be reassigned to point to a different int
- `i` cannot be modified through `p` without use of a cast

`constexpr int *cp = &i;` means:

- `cp` is `const`: it cannot be reassigned
- `i` **can** be modified through `p`

In both cases, `p` is an address constant if and only if `i` has static storage duration.   However, adding `constexpr` will cause a compilation error if applied to something that is not an address constant.

To put that another way: `constexpr int *cp = &i;` and `int *const cp = &i;` are very similar; the only difference is that the first one will fail to compile if `cp` would not be an address constant.