# Force a variable to be const in C++

Tags: c++, templates, casting, constants

The compiler complains at the following code snippet, it says that `cx` isn't a constant expression. And since `cx` isn't constant, it is invalid to pass it in as a template argument of the function `T()`. However, isn't `getFoo()` a const function? Thus isn't `x` const and hence `cx` const? And even if `x` is not, isn't `cx` forced to be const with the const identifier?

What should I do to make `cx` const and be successfully passed as a valid template argument of `T()`?

```
    //M is an instance of class C
    unsigned int x = M.getFoo(); //isn't this supposedly be constant?
    const unsigned int cx = x;
    C<cx> Mt = M.T<cx>();
```

Calling the following 2 public member function of class C:

```
    const int getFoo() const{    
        return foo; //a private variable which value is set in the constructor 
    }
```

```
    <template unsigned int ROWS>
    const C<ROWS> T() const{
        //after some declarations and computations...
        return Ct;
    }
```

Comment: `const` and "compile time const" are not always the same thing. Look into `constexpr`.

Comment: Elaborate please? Thanks! It seems the constexpr is a c++11 specific expression

Comment: `const` just means it can't change once set (it could be set at runtime). `constexpr` can be used to give you a compile time constant if possible - basically it tells the compiler to calculate the answer if the arguments are also `constexpr`. So in your example it would mean that `getFoo` and the constructor would need to be `constexpr`. If the compiler can, it will calculate the answer for you - the rules here are many, so you'll need to play with the code and see if it works.

Comment: C++ is **not** C is **not** C++! That is C++, not C! (Do not add a tag, just because it starts with the same letter as your language)

Comment: Your answer to your question is a subset of the answers you'll find at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const.