# This code is not compiling c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I have this code, but it's not working, I'm using vs2010

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Pass by value 
constexpr float exp(float x, int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 :
        n % 2 == 0 ? exp(x * x, n / 2) :
        exp(x * x, (n - 1) / 2) * x;
};
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is it suppose to do

Comment: Please include your compiler error output.

Comment: When you tried to compile you got a message with a bunch of info. Did you even read it?

Comment: vs2010 has very limited support of C++11, `constexpr` is one of the unsupported feature. Upgrade your compiler.

Comment: Alot on compress code... either edit with errors or/and split ur code to debug it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword **constexpr** was introduced in C++11 and improved in C++14. It means constant expression. Like **const**, it can be applied to variables so that a compiler error will be raised if any code attempts to modify the value. Unlike `const`, `constexpr` can also be applied to functions and class constructors. `constexpr` indicates that the value, or return value, is constant and, if possible, will be computed at compile time. A `constexpr` integral value can be used wherever a `const` integer is required, such as in template arguments and array declarations. And when a value can be computed at compile time instead of run time, it can help your program can run faster and use less memory. check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956974.aspx)

The `constexpr` is **not** supported in `vs2010`, but it's supported on `vs2015`, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) to know what's supported on `vs`, actually `vs2010` is not fully support of `C++11`, so you may update your compiler here.

So you may use vs2015 or you may not use the `constexpr` here, and you may check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const) to see what's the difference between the `const` and `constexpr`, so if possible to use `const` instead of `constexpr` is possible for you.

The mainly difference between them as in the previous link is:

- **const** applies for variables, and prevents them from being modified in your code.
- **constexpr** tells the compiler that this expression results in a compile time constant value, so it can be used in places like array lengths, assigning to const variables, etc.