# static const vs constexpr member fields in C++11/14?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, constexpr

What is the difference between these member variables:

```
struct my_class {
    static const int i = 0;
    static constexpr int j = 0;
};
```

If my understanding is correct, I'm able to use both `i` and `j` as compile time constants. That is, both `std::array<int, my_class::i>` and `std::array<int,my_class::j>` should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \`constexpr\` and \`const\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const)

Comment: After reading that question, i can't still figure out the answer to my question :-)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi i want know what difference does it make when the constexpr is static. that is a little bit different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference for members of integral or enumeration type (as in your example). For all other types, constant expressions [require `constexpr`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2):

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
> - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-volatile const object with a preceding
>     initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or […]
> - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`, or that refers to a non-mutable sub-object of such
>     an object, or […]