# Prefer constexpr over const

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

`constexpr` sometimes implies `const`

Should one - in those cases - always prefer `constexpr` over `const` due to for example run time speed-ups or are there any down sides?

Comment: I didn't ask about what the difference between `constexpr` and `const` is but rather if you should prefer one over the other. In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19137473/4773274) answer @DarioOO asked the same question without getting an answer. So, I don't understand the downvoter(s) and why it should be a duplicate to the mentioned question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes, you should prefer constexpr as long as your expression can be and should be evaluated at compile time.

See this question for more detail:
[Difference between `constexpr` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const)

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` means that the compiler knows it is constant and can compute its value. This allows you to use it in compile-time constructs such as templates, and potentially allows the compiler to do exact optimizations.

If it can be `constexpr`, let it be.