# When to use const over constexpr variables in C++

Tags: c++, constants

I know the difference between `const` and `constexpr`, this is not a question answered by simply re-stating their differences.

Rather I would like to know practical use-cases where you would prefer `const` over `constexpr` variables.

Cases like const references or const methods, etc. are obviously excluded as `const` does something entirely different for them.

The only case I can think of are values that should never change but are initialized from a value unknown at compile-time (read from a file, received from a socket, etc.).

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456058/prefer-constexpr-over-const) but it did not answer my question.

Comment: I think the question you link to (and the question that _that_ then links to_) make it clear enough: use `constexpr` when you can - it sometimes lets the compiler generate better code.  If there's a case when you can't use it (because the function result or the value you want to put in a variable is computed at runtime, rather than being known at compile time), use `const` instead.  That said, the compiler is often smart enough to figure that out anyway these days, but there's nothing like hedging your bets.

Comment: "_The only case I can think of are values that should never change but are initialized from a value unknown at compile-time_": That is pretty much the answer.