# constexpr in C++11 and C++14 (not a difference to const keyword)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

In the "Exploring C++17 and beyond" presentation by Mike Isaacson at one point (https://youtu.be/-ctgSbEfRxU?t=2907) there is question about writing:

```
const constexpr ....
```

vs single const. Mike said that in C++11 constexpr implies const and in C++14 it does not.
Is it true?
I've tried to find prove for that but I couldn't.

I'm not asking about difference between const and constexpr (as a lot of other questions) but about difference in constexpr in two versions of C++ standard.

Comment: In C++11, constexpr on member functions implies the constness of that member function. This implication has been removed in C++14.

Comment: @dyp: I don't follow. A constant member function would have the `const` keyword trailing the argument list, not preceding it as in this question (`const constexpr`). What am I missing?

Comment: In the answer over here [Difference between constexpr and const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const) the example is  `constexpr const int* NP = &N;`, and you need both because they affect different parts of the declaration. That hasn't changed between language versions.

Comment: @IInspectable That is true, `const constexpr` would not affect the constness of a member function. However, it is the only difference regarding constness that I'm aware of between C++11 and C++14.

Comment: In C++11: §7.1.5/8: "A constexpr specifier for a non-static member function that is not a constructor declares that member
function to be const." In C++14 there is no such statement,

Answer (score 0):

Consider this piece of code:

```
struct T { 
  int x;

  constexpr void set(int y) {
    x = y;
  }
};

constexpr T t = { 42 };

int main() {
  t.set(0);
  return 0;
}
```

It should compile in C++14, but give an error in C++11 as if the member function `set` was declared `const`. This is because `constexpr` implies `const` in C++11, while this is not true anymore in subsequent versions of the standard.

The `constexpr` keyword guarantees that the object will not be dynamically initialized at runtime. In case of functions, it guarantees that the function can be evaluated at compile-time. In C++11, this was confounded with "being stored in read-only memory", but this was soon recognized as an error.

In C++14, moreover, `constexpr` functions and members are much more capable. They can modify non-`const` objects, for instance, so they cannot be implicitly `const`.