# Why constexpr implicit conversion doesn't always work?

Tags: c++, casting, g++

```
#include <iostream>

struct Index {
    constexpr operator int() const { return 666; }
};

template <int i> void foo() {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

void wrapper(Index index) {
    foo<index>();
}

int main() {
    Index index;
//    foo<index>(); // error: the value of ‘index’ is not usable in a constant expression
    wrapper(index);
}
```

Hello, everyone.

I'm using a constexpr conversion of a variable "index" to an `int` value, which is substituted to a "foo" templated function.
If I directly call `foo<index>()` from "main", I get a compiler error.
If the same call is done from the "wrapper", then everything compiles and works fine.

What am I missing there?

Compile command: `g++ -std=c++14 main.tex` with g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6).

Comment: I think this is a bug in gcc. Clang appears to accept both: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f8b60e1f2dea54d

Comment: Thanks, I was not thinking in this direction

Comment: And gcc 6.3 also accepts it [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf0525ccda6957ae).

Comment: If I change the code to "foo<(int)index>();" in main, then it passes the compilation. It seems that the compiler treats function parameter and variable declared in the function body in different way.

Comment: Why do you need to use constexpr and const both together?

Comment: @Ali.Ghodrat It just happened, for no reason.

Comment: Then take a look here, I think you can find your answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const

Comment: @Ali.Ghodrat Thanks.

Comment: This is a problem with your compiler. The newest version of [gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/iu1QG7), [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/z7WSdc) and [msvc](https://godbolt.org/g/La3k9z) all compile your code effortlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar error was reported [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58969). It was first reported with GCC 4.9.0

In the analysis provided:

> This is a GCC bug. It appears to be some sort of confusion in the way GCC handles internal linkage non-type template parameters of pointer type.

It has since been resolved.