# C++11: Is there any reason to declare application default value as 'constexpr'

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have an application that has some default values.

Is there any significant difference between:

```
const int MEANING_OF_LIFE = 42;
```

and:

```
constexpr int MEANING_OF_LIFE = 42;
```

?

I understand that `constexpr` value can be used as parameters in `constexpr` functions, but what is if I only assign these values to some variables?

**UPDATE**:

This question is different from [Difference between `constexpr` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const) because it talks about a specific context of `constexpr` usage and requires a specific answer.

Comment: In your "particular" snippet. They are both *core constant expressions*. However you want to prefer the `constexpr` version because it provides more guarantees should you change later decide to change the initializer to some runtime value.

Comment: "Is there any significant difference between ?" No. Chances are most modern compilers will generate the exact same instructions for those two lines of code.