# Using constexpr when a value is non-const but initialized with a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

For some reason I have a hard time grasping how to correctly use `constexpr`.

Is the situation described in the title an appropriate place to use it? i.e:

```
void foo()
{
    static constexpr const size_t MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 20 * 1024 * 1024;

    constexpr size_t bufferSize = 1024 * 1024; // Initialized with constant expression
    std::vector<char> buffer(bufferSize, ' ');

    //...

    if (some_condition())
    {
        bufferSize = get_random_value_at_runtime(); // Assigned a new 'non-constexpr' value
        buffer.resize(bufferSize, ' ');
    }

    //...   
}
```

Kind regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the situation described in the title an appropriate place to use it?

Wrong.

```
constexpr size_t bufferSize = 1024 * 1024; // Initialized with constant expression

// ...

    bufferSize = get_random_value_at_runtime();
```

`constexpr` implies (is also) `const`.

You can't re-assign a `const` variable.

Comment: Interesting, reading answers from [Difference between `constexpr` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const) made me think they are completely independent from one another.

Comment: @notanalien In your linked answer it has *When can I / should I use both, const and constexpr together?

A. In object declarations. This is never necessary when both keywords refer to the same object to be declared. constexpr implies const.* Which is the same as what max66 said.

Comment: @notanalien - they can be indipendent when they are used for methods (member functions) of structs/classes, but only starting from C++14; in C++11 `constexpr` methods are also `const`.  Anyway, a `constexpr` variable is ever (also C++14 and C++17) also `const`.