# Use of const in c++

Tags: c++11, constants, constexpr

Please see this code snippet. Why it is getting compiled and generating output when the value of k is decided at the runtime?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

constexpr auto calcfactorialcompiletime(int k) {
    int ans = 1;
    for( int i=1; i <=k; ++i) {
        ans = ans*i;

    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {

    int k;
    cin>>k;
    const auto ans = calcfactorialcompiletime(k);  
    cout<<ans;
    //ans = 9;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: After checking "Related" list, it seems that this one suits this better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const?rq=1

Comment: The `constexpr` for a function only requires that this function must be evaluable at compile time if the passed arguments are known. So `cin>>k` **within** the `constexpr` would be forbidden.

Comment: `constexpr` (confusingly, but from a standard writing perspective understandably) means "there exist arguments for which this function produces a constant expression", not "this function will always return a constant expression".

Comment: Also, what's with the close votes not working?

Comment: @t.niese True, but there was a close vote before I voted and afterwards it still only displayed one close vote... Probably just caching or so but still confused me.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I would guess `R2RT` removed the close vote for the first dup because it did not match. Maybe at the same time when you added your close vote.

Comment: also, question  sounds like OP is confused by const in main() too. Local `const` variables are just that - variables, which cannot be changed after initialization. Their initialization happens before first use in scope