# Difference between `constexpr` and `#define`

Tags: c++, macros, constexpr

So I read the interesting answers about what are the [differences between constexpr and const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const) but I was curious about are the differences between #define and constexpr ? I feel like constexpr is just a #define where the type can be chosen.

Comment: Having an explicit type is kind of important to help avoid mistakes and the problems those mistakes could lead to.

Comment: I agree, but that's the only difference ?

Comment: `#define` directives create macro substitution, while `constexpr` variables are special type of variables. They literally have nothing in common beside the fact that before `constexpr` (or even `const`) variables were available, macros were sometimes used when currently `constexpr` variable can be used. But both have wide area of applications which are not overlapping with each other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Statements defined using `#define` are called macros. And macros are used in a multitude of uses.

1. We can use them to conditionally compile sections of code.

```cpp
#ifdef ONE
int AddOne(int x) { return x + 1; }

#else
int AddTwo(int x) { return x + 2; }

#endif
```

2. When we don't need to store constants in a variable.

```cpp
#define MAX_BOUND 1000
#define MIN_BOUND 10
```

3. For places where we can use a macros to change the type of data.

```cpp
#ifdef USE_WIDE_CHAR
#define TEXT(...)    L##__VA_ARGS__

#else
#define TEXT(...)    __VA_ARGS__

#endif
```

4. To define keywords based on a condition.

```cpp
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)

#else
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)

#endif
```

Since they are resolved before the actual compilation phase, we can make small improvement to the source code depending on certain factors (platforms, build systems, architecture, etc...).

`constexpr` essentially states that a variable or function *can be* resolved at compile time, but is not guaranteed.

> I feel like constexpr is just a #define where the type can be chosen.

Its not completely true. As I stated before, because they are resolved before the compilation phase, we can take some advantages of it. The only common use would be for constant values which the compiler could easily replace as an optimization. Apart from that, the use cases are different.

Answer (score 13):

You are quite correct.

`#define` (also called a 'macro') is simply a text substitution that happens during preprocessor phase, *before* the actual compiler. And it is obviously not typed.

`constexpr` on the other hand, *happens* during actual parsing. And it is indeed typed.
Comes without saying that, wherever you can, using `constexpr` is a bit safer.

Comment: Just to clarify for myself (and validate my testing in g++). I understand that constexpr compiles differently depending on the type, but if we're talking purely about built-in types, constexpr should result in a zero cost abstraction over #define, right?