# Where to define constants for use in a template member variable of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, scope, header-files

Suppose I want to define a class `Foo` which has a member variable that is also a template `Bar<int num> baz`. Also suppose that I always want `num` to be some particular value (say 5) for `baz` as defined in `Foo`. Then presumably I could accomplish this as follows:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Bar<5> baz;
};
```

However, this would be introducing a magic number which is typically not good programming practice. I have considered defining a constant in the class definition a la `const int num = 5;`, but that would create an extra integer for every instance of `Foo`, which is not ideal if I have lots of instances. I have also considered defining a constant variable outside the class definition but in the header file. This has the advantage of being seen in the `.cpp` file, but pollutes the global name space.

My question is, what is the most stylistically appropriate way to accomplish this goal? Ideally there would be some variable which is only visible to the header and `.cpp` file, and which can be used in the template call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \`constexpr\` and \`const\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const)

Comment: You might have `static constexpr` member.

Comment: @S.M. that question halfway answers mine -- the other piece was the `static` keyword to keep from allocating an `int` for every instance of `Foo`. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2):

You want a single `static` variable, common to all instances of `Foo`.

```
class Foo
{
private:
    static constexpr int num = 5;
    Bar<num> baz;
};
```

For the same reason magic numbers are considered *bad*, you also probably want a variable name more informative than `num`.