# C++ Why does one need to mark a constant-expression eligible function as constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Why do I need to mark functions that satisfy the criteria for constant-expression as `constexpr` to actually use them as constant expression?

Take this example (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const?rq=1)):

```cpp
template<int N>
 class list
 { };

 constexpr int sqr1(int arg)
 { return arg * arg; }

 int sqr2(int arg)
 { return arg * arg; }

 int main()
 {
   const int X = 2;
   list<sqr1(X)> mylist1;  // OK: sqr1 is constexpr
   list<sqr2(X)> mylist2;  // wrong: sqr2 is not constexpr
 }
```

why do I have to mark `sqr2` as `constexpr`? Isn't the compiler able to understand that that function satisfies the criteria for constant-expression? If it does the check for `sqr1`, why can't it do it for `sqr2` and allow `sqr2` to be used as a constant expression even without explicitly marking it?

Comment: By reading that, yes, it seems so. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

All template parameters must be known at compile time. Template is just recipe to create code. Code is generated when template is instantiated with all required template parameters.

So `list<sqr2(X)>` fails, since `sqr2` can't be evaluated at compile time. Only `constexpr` (or `consteval`) functions can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: This is how C++ works, granted. My question was "why does C++ works this way". Why can't the compiler check `sqr2` at compile-time and decide whether it can evaluate it or not. My understanding is that it capable of doing that - for example it performs this check on `sqr1` to see whether you can mark it with `constexpr` or not.