# Check each member of a template parameter pack for equality

Tags: c++, c++20

So, I already have a workable solution, but i want to know if there is any other way to handle this, in case i'm missing something obvious and simple.

What i want to express

```
if((a==c)||...)
```

where `c` is a parameter pack and `a` is a variable. Basically I want it expanded to

```
if( (a == c1) || (a == c2) ... etc)
```

As a MRE

```
  template <typename A, typename... C>
  void foo(A a, C... c) const
  {
      if((a == c)||...)
        return;
  }
```

The solution i ended up going with was

```
if (
    [](auto a, auto c1, auto c2)
      {
        return a.value == c1 || a.value == c2;
      }(a, c...))
```

Comment: Should there be any type constraints? Should the `C`s be the same type, or do you expect different types for each of them? Should they be implicitly converted to `A` when doing equality check, or should each of them have an `operator==(A, C)` defined?

Comment: They are all of the same type, the same type as `A`. Simple intrinsic types

Comment: Also, the last snippet you showed wouldn't work if you have more than 2 `c`s.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep yeah :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What i want to express
>
> ```
> if((a==c)||...)
> ```
>
> where c is a parameter pack and a is a variable. Basically I want it
> expanded to
>
> ```
> if( (a == c1) || (a == c2) ... etc)
> ```

C++17 [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) should be enough, which will expand what you expect

```
template <typename A, typename... C>
  void foo(A a, C... c) 
  {
    if(((a == c)|| ...))
      return;
  }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/foE6GETMh)

Comment: Does that apply to the conditions of `constexpr`? Here in the following post: [What's the difference between `constexpr` and `const`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/whats-the-difference-between-constexpr-and-const)  it says -> ***"Apart from typedefs and static asserts, only a single return statement is allowed."***

Comment: @Const That was a restriction in c++11 and was relaxed/removed since c++14.