# Why is constexpr not interchangeable with const in this instance?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constants, constexpr

I have looked at some of the previous posts related to `constexpr`, especially this one:

[What's the difference between constexpr and const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/whats-the-difference-between-constexpr-and-const)

My understanding based on reading on the topic is that `constexpr` denotes a memory location (object, function et al.) that can be determined fully at compile-time.

Consider the following simple code:

```
  //code.h

#ifndef CODE_H
#define CODE_H

#include<vector>
#include<numeric>
#include<cstddef>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::iota;
using std::size_t;
using std::for_each;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//template<typename T, constexpr size_t s, constexpr T min>
template<typename T, const size_t s, const T min>
class obj{
  public:
   obj();
   obj(const obj&)=delete;
   obj& operator=(const obj&)=delete;
   void print();

  protected:

  private:
  vector<T>v = vector<T>(s); 
};


//template<typename T, constexpr size_t s, constexpr T min>
template<typename T, const size_t s, const T min>
obj<T,s,min>::obj(){
 iota(v.begin(), v.end(), min); 
}

//template<typename T, constexpr size_t s, constexpr T min>
template<typename T, const size_t s, const T min>
void obj<T,s,min>::print(){
 for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const T& t){cout << t << " ";});
 cout << endl;
 return;
}

#endif

//main.cpp

#include "code.h"

int main (){
  obj<int,5,0> V;
  V.print();
  return 0;
}
```

In `code.h` above, if I were to substitute the template header with the template header using `constexpr` (commented out in the code), the compilation stops at the first encounter of the template header, with `g++ 11.3.1` using `-Wfatal-errors` and `-std=c++17`, with the following error:

I

```
n file included from main.c:1:
code.h:17:22: error: a parameter cannot be declared ‘constexpr’
   17 | template<typename T, constexpr size_t s, constexpr T min>
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Note that I am using `constexpr 5` and `constexpr 0` in main.c for initializing the template. My idea of using `constexpr` in the template header is to restrict the user of the template to using compile-time constants in initializing the template. If I were to use `const` instead, the code compiles and runs with the expected output.

So, why isn't `constexpr` interchangeable with `const` in this instance?

Comment: @user17732522 And pray why so?

Comment: Neither const nor constexpr are necessary in template non type parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constexpr` is not permitted on function or template parameters, only top-level on variable and function declarations.

An object declaration with `constexpr` requires that the declaration has an intializer that is a constant expression so that the compiler always knows the value of the object at compile-time as a constant, but a parameter can't have such an initializer as the parameter is initializer by the caller. So it doesn't have any analogues meaning to `constexpr` as top-level specifier on a variable declaration and is therefore not permitted.

There have been proposals to add something like `constexpr` function parameters with slightly different meaning, but nothing has been accepted for the standard.

(`const` in the template parameter itself is also redundant by the way. When the non-type template parameter is of non-class type, then it is prvalue when used in an expression, which has `const` stripped anyway. If it is a class-type, then it is a lvalue that has `const` added to it automatically. So there is basically no difference.)