# Updating const variable value in C++

Tags: c++, constants

I know that we change const variable value  this way in C(by changing it into non-const).

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    const int var = 10; 

    int *ptr = &var; 
    *ptr = 5; 

    printf("var = %d\n", var); 

    return 0; 
}
```

**similar thing (using a pointer) in C++ gives me a compilation error**

How can I update the const variable value in C++?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just make it non-const instead?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was a possibility of doing it in C++ as in C and if yes, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing the value of const variable in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006161/changing-the-value-of-const-variable-in-c)

Comment: Is it even legal to do that in C?

Comment: @Roy2551 I have gone through that question. There, he wants to make sure that his value doesnt get changed.

Comment: @RamPrabodhInduri Ah, okay. So this is just for learning purposes. Got it (I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying a `const` value through any mechanism (including casting away const-ness) results in "undefined behavior" (UB) which means that you cannot reason about the behavior of the program.  The compiler is allowed to assume that `const` values will never change.  Based on that assumption, the compiler might:

- Store `const` values in read-only memory pages; attempting assignment through the pointer would then cause an access violation.
- Inline the `const` value wherever it is used.  Because you take a pointer, the compiler will likely also emit some kind of storage for the value (on the stack most likely) so that it has a memory location that can be pointed to, but modifying this value will not cause the inlined values to change.
- Something else, possibly including *both* of the above.

Which one it does can depend on the optimization level selected.

A program that assigns to a `const` value is effectively "nonsense" and has no meaningful interpretation.

Note that this is UB in both C and C++.  You just need to twist the C++ compiler's arm a bit more to get the code to compile (`int *ptr = const_cast<int *>(&var);`).  The C standard permits implicit discarding of a `const` qualifier in some contexts; the C++ standard is a lot more strict about this.

Most C compilers will emit a warning on `int *ptr = &var;` regarding discarding of the `const` qualifier.  I would strongly recommend compiling with all warnings enabled *and converted to errors* (`-Wall -Werror` on gcc).  That would cause the C compiler to also refuse to compile this code.

---

Note that casting `const` away from a pointer (or reference) and assigning to the target is *not* UB when the value was not declared `const`:

```
// non-const value
int x = 10;

// take a pointer to x and store it in a pointer-to-const
const int *y = &x;

// cast away the const-ness of the pointer target
int *z = const_cast<int *>(y);

// this is fine; z points at x which is not const
*z = 5;
```

However, if you find yourself needing `const_cast` then most likely you are either (1) doing some crazy template metaprogramming, or (2) approaching the problem wrong.

Comment: I'll give you one better, and say that if it's not storing them in const pages, it's because it's inlining them in the assembly code itself.

Comment: Also, I have another question, If a functions return type is const, what does it mean?

Comment: @RamPrabodhInduri There is no such thing in C++ as a const return value because that concept doesn't make sense. A function can return a _reference to a const value_ but this is something different. Can you give an example of some code where you think this is happening?

Comment: @Roguebantha Indeed, good point. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: @cdhowie my bad, i framed it wrong this is what i wanted to ask                                        struct cmp {
 bool operator() (const pair<int, int> &a, const pair<int, int> &b)                   ***const*** {
  int lena = a.second - a.first + 1;
  int lenb = b.second - b.first + 1;
  if (lena == lenb) return a.first < b.first;
  return lena > lenb;
 }
};     what does the const (the one with *** ) just before function description do in the following code, The code is a comparator function for user defined priority_queu in C++

Comment: @RamPrabodhInduri That indicates that the member function `cmp::operator()` can operate on a `const cmp` object. The implicit `this` pointer within that member is effectively typed `const cmp *`. Functors are usually passed around either as const values or by reference-to-const, so without the `const` there, `operator()` could not be invoked on const `cmp` values or references thereto.

Comment: Or (3) [working with some legacy not const-correct system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2673508/10957435).

Comment: @Chipster _(puts fingers in ears)_ LALALALALALA THOSE DON'T EXIST LALALALALALALA