# What is a properly way to iterate a char* string? Getting "corrupt" values

Tags: c++, string, char, iteration, string-iteration

When I was trying to iterate a number (transformed to binary with bitset library) I managed this solution

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

void iterateBinary(int num) {
    char *numInBinary = const_cast<char*>(std::bitset<32>(num).to_string().c_str());

    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
        char bit = numInBinary[i];
        std::cout << i << ": " << bit << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But founded those weird characters in the output

[image: Weird output]

I already implemented a solution to my initial idea with `for (char bit : numInBinary)` and without `c_str()` transformation, but I'm still curious about what happened (maybe memory problems?) or which can be a better way to iterate a `char*` string

Also remark that the "corrupt" values in the output are no the same on each ejecution and only appears at the end, why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Most of time when you need to use `const_cast`. It might be a [wrong usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2673508/4123703)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wierd output using const char\*, to\_string() and c\_str()](//stackoverflow.com/q/31690826/90527)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/ef3b3PWbM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lifetime of the string returned by `to_string()`, and into which the pointer returned by `c_str()` points, ends at the end of the full expression.

This means after the line

```
char *numInBinary = const_cast<char*>(std::bitset<32>(num).to_string().c_str());
```

the pointer `numInBinary` will be dangling and trying to access through it will result in undefined behavior.

You need to store the return value from `to_string()` so that it lives long enough, e.g.

```
auto numInBinary = std::bitset<32>(num).to_string();
```

There is also no need for a `char*` pointer, since `std::string` can just be indexed directly.

Also, if you think you need to use `const_cast` anywhere, rethink it. Except for very specific scenarios where you take care of const correctness by unusual means, `const_cast` is almost surely the wrong approach and likely to result in undefined behavior down the line.